# NodeJS HTTPS request to Intersango.com

Tags: javascript, api, node.js, https, bitcoin

There is something wrong with the request I'm making and I can't figure it out. It seems everything is in order according to the [API spec](https://intersango.com/api.php).

Here is the code:

```
var request = require('https').request;

var opts = {
  host: 'intersango.com',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/api/ticker.php',
  port: 443,
  accept: '*/*',
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0' } };

var req = request(opts, function (result) {
        result.setEncoding('utf8');
        var buffer = '';
        result.on('data', function(data) {
            buffer += data;
        });
        result.on('end', function() {
            console.log('<- Received ' + buffer.length + ' bytes');
            var data = JSON.parse(buffer);
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('warning: problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

console.log('-> ' + opts['method'] + ' ' + opts['host'] + ':' + opts['port'] + opts['path']);

req.end();
```

Here is the output:

```
$> node test.intersango.js
-> GET intersango.com:443/api/ticker.php
warning: problem with request: socket hang up
```

Interestingly, if you go to https://intersango.com/api/ticker.php in your browser its fine, **but not if you just go to [intersango.com:443/api/ticker.php](http://intersango.com:443/api/ticker.php)**. I tried some [other ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers?highlight=https) but it just gives `warning: problem with request: connect ECONNREFUSED`

*Note: trying POST doesnt help either*

Comment: code works fine for me. Maybe it was a temporary problem on intersango's side. Which version of node are you using?

Comment: Im using `v0.9.7`, requests to other services work fine. Also, Im issuing this from Amazons EC2.

Comment: OK well this pretty much means its due to EC2... Ill go restart my instance now...

Comment: or try a different node version as `0.9.x` is the unstable branch

Comment: I got a different hostname on EC2 and now the server is returning `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE` D: I'll try downgrading my node tomorrow.

Comment: Working on my Ubuntu with `0.8.19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm, downgrading Node did solve the issue.